# How do I match one list index with its related index in an other list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to work with multiple lists and I am new to Python. So, say I have 2 lists:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4]
```

and

```
listb = [up, right, left, down]
```

`listb` are labels for `lista`. If I'm finding say the largest number from `lista`, I know how to do this part, how would I get the label for this number from `listb`? Since the answer is unknown and can change over time. I'm not sure how to get the related item from the other list.

Simplest answers are welcome! Its an assignment for a class. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Take a look at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: instead of using list function, look in dict function, its better fit for what you trying to do.

Comment: Create a dictionary `d = dict(zip(lista, listb))`. Call `m = max(lista)`, and use the value `m` to lookup the label with `d[m]`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit the lists. So can' turn them into a dictionary. Also we haven't discussed the zip() at all so I don't know that I should use it?

Answer (score 0):

Get index from the `lista`:

```
i = lista.index(max(lista))
```

With this index get label from `listb`:

```
label = listb[i]
```